# redirect_uri_mismatch google plus login with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-plus, google-plus-signin

I am trying to implement login with Google Plus in my website using JavaScript. My origin URL is `http://www.locallylahore.com` and my redirect URL is `http://www.locallylahore.com/oauth2callback/`. I tried removing `www` from my URLs, but it didn't work.

My website URL is `http://locallylahore.com/map.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure to add `http://locallylahore.com` to the "JavaScript origins" in the Google Developers Console.
Since your website is reachable with and without www I would keep both variants in there. If you try to sign-in at `http://www.locallylahore.com/map.php` you will see that you don't get the error since you apparently already have the www-variant correctly in the Javascript origins.

Please be aware that changing the origin can take several minutes before it is active, so trying to sign-in right after changing the setting won't work.

Comment: I have checked with both `WWW` and without it but it didn't worked and yes i have waited for few minutes but even that didn't work anything else ? which you think can be happened with it ?